# passing Parameter from ASP-Page to Angularjs-module

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

In an ASP Page I have a AngularJS modules directly applied. The ASP-page get from the server a parameter, that is to be used in the module. Like this (foo is the parameter):

```
<script>
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('myController', function($scope ) {
     $scope.foo = @Model.foo;
...
```

Now I would like to outsource the module in a separate JS file.
How can I inject the parameter  into the module then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define parameters in global scope, and use it in angular app.

Index.cshtml:

```
<!-- this shoud be initialized before angular appplication -->
<script type='text/javascript'>
  window.backendParams = {
    foo: @Model.foo ,
    bar: @Model.bar
  }
</script>
```

app.js:

```
myApp.controller('myController', function($scope ) {
     $scope.foo = window.backendParams.foo;
...
```

Comment: @bogus, look at answer.